# Calculating Probabilities for a cumulative distribution function within a given inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

[image]

Given that K = 1/36, I require some help understanding (b)

•   Pr(1/2 ≤ X ≤ 1)

Is re-written as such:

Pr(X ≤ 1) - Pr(X < 1/2)

I do not understand why!

Is it because

Pr(X ≤ 1) is solved as F(1) and

Pr(X ≤ 1) - Pr(X < 1/2) = Pr(X ≤ 1) + (1 - Pr(X < 1/2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand the difference between a probability density function and a cumulative distribution function.

The cumulative distribution function, which in your case is $F(x)$, always gives the value for $P(X \leq x)$

So, $F(1)$ would give you $P(X\leq1)$ and $F(\frac{1}{2})$ would give you $P(X\leq\frac{1}{2})$. In order to find $P(\frac{1}{2} < X \leq 1)$, you calculate, $F(1) - F(\frac{1}{2})$

- Edited as per suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

$$\{X\leq 1\}=\{X<\frac{1}{2}\}\cup\{\frac{1}{2}\leq X\leq 1\}$$ and these sets are disjoint so that: $$P\{X\leq 1\}=P\{X<\frac{1}{2}\}+P\{\frac{1}{2}\leq X\leq 1\}$$
or equivalently: $$P\{\frac{1}{2}\leq X\leq 1\}=P\{X\leq 1\}-P\{X<\frac{1}{2}\}$$

Comment: so to solve these problems do I always start with a Probability that can be solved, and then work to find how this is defined in terms of the other value (1/2) ... and the sets are going to be always disjoint, so it will simply be case of (+) ... is there another way of looking at it? Because this method could get super confusing with complex equations.

Comment: This is what 'lies under it' or 'where it comes from'. In fact the additivity of probability measures. The more you deal with it (and gain mathematical maturity), the less you need to go back to these basics. If the equations are complex then blaim the equations for being super confusing. Not the method.